# How to get ID of element clicked in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-click

```
<div ng-repeat="account in accounts" class="widget-container added_address">    
    <div id="address-{{$index}}"
         class="btc_public_address"
         ng-click="pubAddress.getClick(address-{{$index}}">
             {{account.address}}
    </div>
```

^ Above the div is in a ng-repeat, I have about 4 divs which ids: address-1, address-2, address-3, and address-4 for IDs.

I tried to simply pass the IDs in the getClick function, but got the following error:

**Error: [$parse:syntax] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.19/$parse/syntax?**

App code:

```
$scope.pubAddress = {};
$scope.pubAddress.getClick = function(the_id) {
    console.log(the_id);
    selectAddress(the_id);
};

// code to select text inside ID (works)
function selectAddress(element) {
    var text = document.getElementById(element);
    var range = document.createRange();
    var selection = window.getSelection();
    range.selectNodeContents(text);
    selection.removeAllRanges();
    selection.addRange(range);
};
```

^ Basically I'm trying to make a simple selection of the text inside each div I click on with those IDs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not perform interpolation for the ng-click argument, since it would result in parse error due to the presence of invalid expression (Used to work in very old version of angular though), So just use string concatenation.

i.e

```
 ng-click="pubAddress.getClick(address-{{$index}}"
```

should be:

```
 ng-click="pubAddress.getClick('address-' + $index)"
```

And seems like you are using ng-repeat you could use `ng-init` to do it at once.

Ex:-

```
 <div ng-repeat="account in accounts" ng-init="addressId='address' + $index"..>
```

Using `ng-init` adds the property addressId on the child scope created by the ng-repeat and is accessible inside and this property is not watched.

Comment: Ah thanks! 11 mins :) OMG that ng-init is beautiful! Thanks X2 :D

Answer (score 1):

since ng-click is directive that  evaluates express provided as argument so curly braces are not needed

ng-click evaluate it content so you don't need interpolation

[image]

use

```
ng-click="pubAddress.getClick('address-' + $index>
```